# Testing and Exceptions , Mocking

Tags: c#, java, testing

Say I want to test that some code that downloads a file from a storage server is following a specific course of action in the case of a download error ( server is down or credentials are invalid , for example).

I see two ways to test this:

**Choice #1** : Initialize a real download server object with obviously bad credentials ; It will trigger an exception when something tries to do something with conn ;

```
FileServerConnection conn = new FileServerConnection("Invalid User", "Invalid Password");
```

**Choice #2** : Mock the FileServerConnection class and instruct the mock to throw an exception when the FileServerConnection object is constructed;

I know that Choice #2 is preferred to Choice #1 , but I don't see why ..can somebody explain why #2 is better than #1. The only issue I see with #1 at this point ( it's Friday afternoon ) is that it's a much slower test ( albeit one or two seconds slower ).

Cheers !

P.S One advantage of Choice #1 is that it's less lines of code to write :-)

Comment: Choice 1 is not a unit test, it's an integration test.

Comment: True choice #1 is an integration test , never said it was a unit test in my original post though ; Then the question becomes : why a unit test and not an integration test in this situation , since the integration test is actually less lines of code to write ;

Comment: @MadSeb - your title literally says Unit Testing ...

Comment: Choice 2 is preferred because it is easier to achieve _and_ it allows you to test the behaviour of your class, which is the objective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that choice #1 depends on another system, and you generally want your unit tests to be independent of things like that.

Your test in choice #2 is testing how your code behaves with bad credentials (what you want), but choice #1 would cause to test how the download server handles improper credentials as well (which is not related to what you want to test here). This makes your test more complicated and more things can go wrong.